# Start date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a four week work schedule start date should be 2022-03-01.
I made code to do that but the problem is:
In java script you can not write start date as it should, but must be at least one month before real start date, and if you change start date, you get different results.
I tried many start dates until I found the best start date is 20-01-27 the result is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="majed" id="schema">
            <form id="myFormsch">
      
                <label for="Datum">Datum:</label>
                <span>
                <input type="text" readonly=""  id="date"placeholder="Klick och välj datum">
                </span>
                <label for="dag">Dag:</label>
                <span>
                <input type="text" readonly="" id="day">
                 </span>
                <label for="Arbetar">Ulf:</label>
                <input type="text" readonly="" id="Arbetar">
            </form>
        </div>
       
        
        
        <script>
      
            $(function () {
                var weekStart = new Date(2022, 01, 27);

                var roster =
                ['Sun week 1 Day 1','Mon week 1 Day 2','Tue week 1 Day 3','Wed week 1 Day 4','Thu week 1 Day 5','Fri week 1 Day 6','Sat week 1 Day 7',
 'Sun week 2 Day 8','Mon week 2 Day 9','Tue week 2 Day 10','Wed week 2 Day 11','Thu week 2 Day 12','Fri week 2 Day 13','Sat week 2 Day 14',
 'Sun week 3 Day 15','Mon week 3 Day 16','Tue week 3 Day 17','Wed week 3 Day 18','Thu week 3 Day 19','Fri week 3 Day 20','Sat week 3 Day 21',
 'Sun week 4 Day 22','Mon week 4 Day 23','Tue week 4 Day 24','Wed week 4 Day 25','Thu week 4 Day 26','Fri week 4 Day 27','Sat week 4 Day 28'];


           
               
                $('#date').datepicker({
                     firstDay: 1 ,
                     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    minDate: weekStart,
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                        var d = new Date(dateText);
                        $.datepicker.iso8601Week(d);
                        
   
   
                        var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) ;
                        var week = Math.floor((days / 7) % 4);
                         $('#week').val(week +1);
                        $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date) +" " +"Week"+" "+ ($.datepicker.iso8601Week(d)))  ;
                        $('#Arbetar').val(roster[(week) * 7 + date.getDay()]);
                        
                       
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

2022-04-03 Sun week 1 Day 1 wrong
it should be sun week 2 day 8 but it is sun week 1 day 1.
I do not know how to solve the problem,
Do you have suggestions for the problem?, please help me
thanks

Comment: Please explain the logic for *"it should be sun week 2 day 8"*. Why is that week 2, and why day 8?

Comment: it is 28 days circle
2022-03-06 Sun week 2 Day 8 right
2022-03-13 Sun week 3 Day 15 right
2022-03-20 Sun week 4 Day 22 right
2022-03-27 Sun week 1 Day 1 right
2022-04-03 Sun week 1 Day 1 wrong

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry. Can you not explain in more detail? I have no idea what you are doing. Why is Sun week 2 Day 8 "right"?? You are not explaining the logic. How do you count? Why are there two outputs? What is the meaning of that? What is `#week`?

Comment: if you run the code snippet and click on Sundays start with Sunday the 2022-03-06 and four more Sundays, you will see that something is wrong in this circle

Comment: I give up. I have no idea what the **logic** is that you want to apply. Please edit your question and explain with a few examples of input, what the corresponding output should be and (important) **why**.

Comment: What is the expected output if you select 2022-03-06 versus what you are getting?

Comment: output should be Sun week 2 Day 8 the word week is the week's circle in 28 days it is always 4 weeks in 28 days

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up and examining your code, I do not see the issue. I do see that in your code you reference an element with `week` as the ID, yet I can find no HTML with this ID.

```js
$(function() {
  var weekStart = new Date(2022, 01, 27);

  var roster = ['Sun week 1 Day 1', 'Mon week 1 Day 2', 'Tue week 1 Day 3', 'Wed week 1 Day 4', 'Thu week 1 Day 5', 'Fri week 1 Day 6', 'Sat week 1 Day 7',
    'Sun week 2 Day 8', 'Mon week 2 Day 9', 'Tue week 2 Day 10', 'Wed week 2 Day 11', 'Thu week 2 Day 12', 'Fri week 2 Day 13', 'Sat week 2 Day 14',
    'Sun week 3 Day 15', 'Mon week 3 Day 16', 'Tue week 3 Day 17', 'Wed week 3 Day 18', 'Thu week 3 Day 19', 'Fri week 3 Day 20', 'Sat week 3 Day 21',
    'Sun week 4 Day 22', 'Mon week 4 Day 23', 'Tue week 4 Day 24', 'Wed week 4 Day 25', 'Thu week 4 Day 26', 'Fri week 4 Day 27', 'Sat week 4 Day 28'
  ];

  $('#date').datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: weekStart,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      //var d = new Date(dateText);
      //$.datepicker.iso8601Week(d);
      var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var week = Math.floor((days / 7) % 4);
      console.log("Days:", days, "Week:", week);
      $('#week').val(week + 1);
      $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date) + " " + "Week" + " " + ($.datepicker.iso8601Week(date)));
      var index = (week * 7) + date.getDay();
      console.log(week + " * 7 + " + date.getDay());
      console.log("index:", index);
      $('#Arbetar').val(roster[index]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="majed" id="schema">
    <form id="myFormsch">
      <label for="Datum">Datum:</label>
      <span><input type="text" readonly id="date" placeholder="Klick och välj datum"></span>
      <label for="dag">Dag:</label>
      <span><input type="text" readonly id="day"></span>
      <label for="Arbetar">Ulf:</label>
      <input type="text" readonly="" id="Arbetar">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything calculates as you laid it out and I since I do not know what the expected output should be, I am guessing it is correct.

**Uodate**

```js
$(function() {
  var weekStart = new Date(2022, 01, 27);

  var roster = ['Sun week 1 Day 1', 'Mon week 1 Day 2', 'Tue week 1 Day 3', 'Wed week 1 Day 4', 'Thu week 1 Day 5', 'Fri week 1 Day 6', 'Sat week 1 Day 7',
    'Sun week 2 Day 8', 'Mon week 2 Day 9', 'Tue week 2 Day 10', 'Wed week 2 Day 11', 'Thu week 2 Day 12', 'Fri week 2 Day 13', 'Sat week 2 Day 14',
    'Sun week 3 Day 15', 'Mon week 3 Day 16', 'Tue week 3 Day 17', 'Wed week 3 Day 18', 'Thu week 3 Day 19', 'Fri week 3 Day 20', 'Sat week 3 Day 21',
    'Sun week 4 Day 22', 'Mon week 4 Day 23', 'Tue week 4 Day 24', 'Wed week 4 Day 25', 'Thu week 4 Day 26', 'Fri week 4 Day 27', 'Sat week 4 Day 28'
  ];

  $('#date').datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    minDate: weekStart,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      //var d = new Date(dateText);
      //$.datepicker.iso8601Week(d);
      var days = Math.floor((date.getTime() - weekStart.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var week = Math.floor(days < 30 ? days / 7 % 4 : (days / 7 % 4) + (Math.floor(days / 30)));
      console.log("Days:", days, "Week:", week);
      $('#week').val(week + 1);
      $('#day').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date) + " " + "Week" + " " + ($.datepicker.iso8601Week(date)));
      var index = (week * 7) + date.getDay();
      console.log(week + " * 7 + " + date.getDay());
      console.log("index:", index);
      $('#Arbetar').val(roster[index]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.6.3/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="majed" id="schema">
    <form id="myFormsch">
      <label for="Datum">Datum:</label>
      <span><input type="text" readonly id="date" placeholder="Klick och välj datum"></span>
      <label for="dag">Dag:</label>
      <span><input type="text" readonly id="day"></span>
      <label for="Arbetar">Ulf:</label>
      <input type="text" readonly="" id="Arbetar">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you run the code in 2022-03-27 results are Sun week 1 Day 1
and if you run the code into 2022-04-03 the result is Sun week 1 Day 1
that is the error in 2022-04-03, the result should be Sun week 2 Day 8

Comment: @majed this would suggest there is an issue in the logic that creates your Index. Days: `34`, `34 / 7 = 4.6`, `4.6 % 4 = 0.5999999999999996` This would Floor to `0`.

Comment: can you help me

Comment: @majed I updated my answer with a more complex algorithm: `var week = Math.floor(days < 30 ? days / 7 % 4 : (days / 7 % 4) + (Math.floor(days / 30)));`

Comment: now the error is in 2022-04-04 result is Mon week 3 Day 16
 the result should be Mon week 2 Day 9

Comment: @majed it's not clear from your code what you are trying to reference or accomplish. Please clarify.